# input pattern не работает для русских букв без флага

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения, html5

Есть такое выражение для ввода адресов сайтов:

```
[-a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-zа-яё]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)
```

на сайте regex101.com оно работает с флагом для юникода /u, а инпут все равно не хочет принимать адреса сайтов на русском. Проверял еще через regexr.com - с английскими все нормально, русские не понимает. Что не так, помогите пожалуйста

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input required id="f-site" pattern="[-a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-zа-яё]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)" type="text" title="Пример: site.ru" name="urs" class="form-control" placeholder="Ссылка на сайт" maxlength="500">
</div>
```

Или как задать этот флаг в инпуте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Экранируйте только те символы, которые внутри символьного класса являются специальными:

```css
input:valid {
  color: black;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input required id="f-site" pattern="[-a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9@:%._+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-zа-яё]{2,6}(?:[?/][-a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9@:%_+.~#?&/=]*)?" type="text" title="Пример: site.ru" name="urs" class="form-control" placeholder="Ссылка на сайт" maxlength="500">
</div>
```

Знак `+` не является специальным, так же как и `/` (который не надо дублировать внутри одного символьного класса).

Comment: но ведь все равно, для site.ru работает, а для сайт.рф нет http://prntscr.com/miyzcd http://prntscr.com/miyzxo А на сайте regex101 работает только с флагом юникода http://prntscr.com/miz0fq

Comment: @JaredBay `сайт.рф` не сработает из-за `\b`. Если граница слова там сигнализирует `/` или `?`, так и надо их указать. `pattern="[-a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9@:%._+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-zа-яё]{2,6}(?:[?/][-a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ0-9@:%_+.~#?&/=]*)?"`

Comment: Спасибо большое!! я уже думал, что где-то в инпуте нужно указывать флаг, что бы русский воспринимал